# Filtering out Non-integers in my array OCTAVE/MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have a code that determines prime factors written as:

```
N=12345678
for i = 2 : N
    q = 0;

    while N/i == floor(N/i)
        N = N/i;
        q = q + 1;
    end

    if q > 0
        fac=i

     if N == 1
            break
        end
    end
end
```

However, I want my desired values which are 2, 3 ,47, and 14593 into one single matrix.

How can I do this?

Comment: As a general tip, please specify the language you are writing in (adding it as a tag is also very useful)

Comment: The code seems to be MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

If as it seems your code is in MATLAB, you simply can do this:

```
N=12345678
fac = [];
for i = 2 : N
    q = 0;
    while N/i == floor(N/i)
        N = N/i;
        q = q + 1;
    end
    if q > 0
        fac=[fac, i];
        if N == 1
            break
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: this worked.  Thank you so much for the input.  Spent forever trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do it yourself on purpose? You could use Matlab's [`factor`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/symbolic/factor.html) function instead,

```
factor(N)
```

which gives the same result.